# How to set custom properties folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cmake, csproj

Let my project structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
|-Properties
  |-AssemblyInfo.cs
  |-Resources.resx
  |-Resources.Designer.resx
|-MyProject.csproj.template
|-foo.cs
|-bar.cs
build
|-Debug_x64
  |-MyProject
    |-MyProject.csproj
```

Basically, my `.csproj` file is in separate build tree. `MyProject.csproj` is generated at configuration time by cmake using `configure_file` and `MyProject.csproj.template` as an input. I don't want to generate `MyProject.csproj` in my source tree since I want the build system to be "out of source". The problem is as follows.

Visual studio and msbuild do not treat the Properties folder as properties. This leads to incorrect `Resources.Designer.resx` file generation: all the code is generated in `MyProject` namespace instead of `MyProject.Properties`.

I guess it's some how related to `AppDesignerFolder` tag in the generated `.csproj`. I tried to provide relative path to the `Properties` folder

```
<AppDesignerFolder>..\..\..\MyProject\Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
```

I tried to provide absolute path:

```
<AppDesignerFolder>C:\Users\yadayada\MyProject\Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
```

But nothing helps.

Is there any idea how to make it work when `Properties` folder and `.csproj` are not in the same directory?

Comment: Create a directory junction (mklink /j) in the directory where the csproj is so it believes there's a properties directory there?

Comment: Thanks!  That's  good idea,  I'll try it.

Comment: @stijn Ok, now VS is able to catch the `Properties` directory, but resource compiler fails to compile anything, since all the resources are added by relative paths.

Comment: Just a hint: the CMake team is in the process of supporting C# projects naively with the next release > version 3.7.0 (see e.g. [this commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/4f78b9ff2df89d5b4104f92251feb0a7f0976d7f)). Maybe yours would also be a good test case.

Comment: Why are relative paths a problem? If they don't point to an existing path then your generated project is wrong? Anyway if you don't get an answer here: I'd post this as a bug on the Microsoft Connect site in order to get proper info. Might take a while though.

Comment: @stijn relative paths become a problem only for `Resource.resx` file. Look, it currently contains relative paths to resources. Once I add `Resource.resx` file to a project via the junction, at compile time it tries to load `..\some_image.bmp` witch points to the project directory instead of source directory. Thus the junction approach requires moving all the resources to a project directory as well.

Comment: @stijn Of course, I can use `configure_file` for `Resource.resx` in order to provide correct paths to resource files. But IMO it looks like really ugly workaround witch makes build system pretty complex.